# spring boot how to autowire bean using yaml file in src/test/resource/

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-test

I'm new to Spring boot (version 1.1.8, spring version 4.0.7) and I need to fix a unit test. The class under test uses another class that has a simple autowired configuration bean. The class of the bean basically looks for a bunch of key value pairs where the keys have a certain prefix. The code itself works perfectly fine using the yaml file in src/main/resources. However, when I run the test case, this bean is null. How do I get the test case to read the yaml file in the src/test/resources directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [@TestPropertySource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestPropertySource.html) annotation for your test class:

```
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:your-tets-properties-file.yml")
```